# Column 'Users.Reputation' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql

I am trying to rank user by number of question asked  by I get

> Column 'Users.Reputation' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Here is the code https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1239556/users-with-most-questions#resultSets

```
select count(OwnerUserId),OwnerUserId,Reputation,DisplayName
from Posts
left join Users on Users.Id = OwnerUserId
where PostTypeId=1
group by OwnerUserId 
order by count(OwnerUserId) desc;
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error seems quite clear:  You need to include all non-aggregated columns in the `GROUP BY`:

```
select count(u.id), p.OwnerUserId, u.Reputation, u.DisplayName
from Posts p left join
     Users u
     on u.Id = p.OwnerUserId
where p.PostTypeId = 1
group by p.OwnerUserId, u.Reputation, u.DisplayName 
order by count(*) desc;
```

I would note that this looks awkward to me; I don't think the `LEFT JOIN` is necessary.  And you can just use `u.id` in the `GROUP BY` and `SELECT`.